# How to center a div with display inline-block under a div with display table?

Tags: html, css

I just want to keep display table for container and display table-cell for h1 (to get it vertically centered) and I want to put an arrow under the h1 and out of the red div

my code is :

```css
.container{
    display:table;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
}
.h1{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.sub{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 30px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">       
    <h1> title 1 </h1>
    <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/dqjb6kqr/15/

Comment: If you're using `position:absolute` there is no need to use `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this way is a little better:

http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/dqjb6kqr/15/

```
<div class="container">
     <h1> title 1 </h1>
</div>

.container {
    display:table;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}

h1 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.container:after {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content:" ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-top-color: #000000;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```